# Open Source .net C# library for Real Time transport Protocol

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, rtp

Is there good open source library for RTP in .net? My intention is to use in Audio and Video Synchronization problem and to increase Frames per second rate.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I don't know much about RTP, but you may want to have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Using_RTP_in_Multicasting.aspx). Also, a Google search for "RTP C#" may help you a bit. Another result from that search includes [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4845258/138757).

Comment: What we have to do in order to make RTP compatible with TCP socket based application.Is there exist any library so we can utilize by making wrappers.

Comment: @Samie Well like I said, I don't know much about RTP. I have never used it before. The Google search is the only advice I can give.