# VoIP App development in xamarin with Xmpp Server

Tags: mono, xmpp, voip

I want to develop a VoIP app with Xamarin and Xmpp server. 
So far the only things that I have found is the openfire and "jitsi meet" for the server side and matrix for the client side. But the matrix has nothing to do with voice streaming and is just for text messaging and "jitsi meet" doesn’t have any sdk for .net client side.
I also have found the red5pro but this has client sdks just for native android and ios development platform and has nothing for Mono.

So what Should I look  for?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's clarify some basics:

- openfire is a XMPP server. Basically, this is all you need on the server side for basic VoIP support.
  Alternatives include [ejabberd](http://ejabberd.im) and [Prosody](https://prosody.im/).
- jitsi meet essentialy already is a VoIP app, so if you want to develop your own, you don't really need that.
- "Jitsi Videobridge" on the other hand can be used to provide a relay server for video conferences. For your first steps with a simple VoIP app, you wont need that either, but if you want your users to be able to create video conferences with many participants, then this helps.

  (Explanation: Normally, when you create a P2P-Video conference, you
  have two options: First, all users send their video data to all
  participants (everybody needs lots of bandwidth), or you pick one
  participant ("host") that receives the video streams of every
  participant end sends them to every other participant. In the second
  case, a normal participant only has to upload his stream once and
  download n streams, whereas the host does most of the work - so only
  that one user needs high bandwidth.
  Jitsi Videobridge can run on a server and act as this conference host (usually a server has a much better bandwidth than a home user), so that none of the participants has to act as a host.
  In simple VoIP applications (without video), this may not be neccessary, as audio streams are usually much smaller than video streams.)

Now, as I said above, in order to write a VoIP app, you basically only need a XMPP server (openfire, prosody and ejabberd should all be sufficient for this use case), a client library that supports **Jingle** and client libraries for the RTP media streams (transfer and display).
Jingle is the name of a XMPP protocol extension that enables **the negotiation** of P2P data streams as they are needed for a VoIP call.
The relevant protocol specifications:

- [XEP 0166: Jingle](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html)
- [XEP-0167: Jingle RTP Sessions](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0167.html)

So what you need to find is a XMPP library with support for the jingle protocol. The [C# Matrix XMPP SDK](http://www.ag-software.net/matrix-xmpp-sdk/) (not to be confused with the "Matrix protocol", which is a different protocol and has nothing to do with XMPP except for having a common goal) is one example of such a library. According to their web site, there is support for Jingle, but I couldn't find any documentation about it.
However, as I mentioned above, Jingle is only about *how to negotiate data streams, not the data streams and VoIP itself*.
So what that library *probably* helps you with is parsing of the Jingle XMPP messages that are needed to set up a RTP data stream.
For displaying and transfering the RTP stream, however, you need additional libraries. For that, have a look at the following SO questions and answers:

- [Open Source .net C# library for Real Time transport Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358230/open-source-net-c-sharp-library-for-real-time-transport-protocol)
- [Streaming Avi files from C# using RTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767491/streaming-avi-files-from-c-sharp-using-rtp)

I hope I could give you some useful hints...

Comment: thank you for your good explanation, Now I'm able to investigate better according to the information you gave.

Comment: so I need a media(or voice) streaming SDK that could work alongside the Matrix SDK, if I'm right, is there any?

Comment: yes, as described above you need code or libraries for XMPP and RTP. So if you receive a call from the XMPP library with some parameters you pass this to your RTP library to transfer the media data (vocde and video)

Comment: I have read the XEP-0166 document and downloaded the jingle.xsd but, my first problem is the registration of users ids that are stored in xmpp server database with the device(or ip address) and I need actually a walkthrough tutorial for basic and fundamental things that I have to implement.