# C# Real time data protocol

Tags: c#, networking, rtp

Is it possible to implement `RTP` (Real-Time Data Protocol) with `C#`?
If so, How?
I've seen a few examples but couldn't find anything proper.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with proper?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that it is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It 100% is. You need to workout what it is being transferred over UDP/TCP (Usually is UDP) and if it uses RTP or RTPCP (This is similar only it also allows the client to stop/start the stream etc), and what data it is sharing, whether its audio, video etc... Here is the specification you will see the structure on page 12. There are RTP parsers for c# if you google around, the structure is very simple though.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550

If you are trying to stream rather than receive the below answer should set you in the right direction

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24173630/12429913

Comment: I am trying to build a video chat application with audio . As I understand from your reply It is possible but it's gonna take some time right ? Also thank you.

Comment: Yea probably, there are plugins for audio and video that should help but its not something you'll be able to throw together and ship in a day.